# Cogs double commands discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

[Unknown Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKPQF.png) [Already playing audio.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xq3ew.png) When I added to my code cogs it a bit broken him. Before I don't have any error, but now when I calling some command it calls twice. Also I'm getting error like Unknown Message, Already playing audio. etc. (twice) Also I pinned some tracebacks in the image. I'm new in discord.py so hope someone will help me, thank you !

main.py

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands
from cogs import embed_command, music

cogs = [embed_command, music]

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.all())
client.remove_command("help")

# for i in range(len(cogs)):
#     cogs[i].setup(client)


for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
    else:
        print(f'Unable to load {filename[:-3]}')


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("\n\tOnline")

client.run('token')
```

in folder cogs: embed_command.py

```
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands


class Embed(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author == self.client.user:
            return
        await self.client.process_commands(message)

    @commands.command()
    async def embed(self, ctx):
        embed_question = discord.Embed(
            title="Enter a title of embed message: ",
            description="||This request will be canceled in 10 seconds!||"
        )
        embed1 = await ctx.send(embed=embed_question)
        try:
            msg = await self.client.wait_for("message", check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author, timeout=10)
            msg_color = await self.client.wait_for("message", check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author,
                                                   timeout=10)
            r = msg_color.content.split(",", 3)[0]
            g = msg_color.content.split(",", 3)[1]
            b = msg_color.content.split(",", 3)[2]
            embed_question_answer = discord.Embed(
                title=msg.content.split("/", 3)[0],
                description=msg.content.split("/", 3)[1],
                color=discord.Color.from_rgb(int(r), int(g), int(b))
            )
            # embed_question_answer.add_field(name=msg.content.split("/", 3)[2], value=msg.content.split("/", 3)[3],
            #                                 inline=False)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed_question_answer)
            await msg.delete()
            await ctx.message.delete()
            await msg_color.delete()
            await embed1.delete()
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            timeout_embed = discord.Embed(
                title="",
                description="***Отмена операции из-за долгого ожидания.***",
                color=0x2f3136
            )
            await ctx.send(embed=timeout_embed, delete_after=5)
            await embed1.delete()
            await ctx.message.delete()

    @commands.command()
    async def clear(self, ctx, amount=5):
        await ctx.message.delete()
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
        embed_answer = discord.Embed(
            title="",
            description=f"***{amount} сообщений(-я, -е) было удалено.***",
            color=0x2f3136
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=embed_answer, delete_after=5)


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Embed(client))
```

in folder cogs: music.py:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl


class Music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def join(self, ctx):
        if ctx.author.voice is None:
            await ctx.send("Вы не находитесь в голосовом канале !")
        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            await voice_channel.connect()
        else:
            await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)

    @commands.command()
    async def disconnect(self, ctx):
        await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

    @commands.command()
    async def play(self, ctx, url):
        if ctx.author.voice is None:
            await ctx.send("Вы не находитесь в голосовом канале !")
        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            await voice_channel.connect()
        else:
            await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)
        ctx.voice_client.stop()
        FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {
            'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5',
            'options': '-vn'
        }
        YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio'}
        vc = ctx.voice_client

        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
            url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
            source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
            vc.play(source)

    @commands.command()
    async def pause(self, ctx):
        ctx.voice_client.pause()
        await ctx.send("Приастоновлено.")

    @commands.command()
    async def resume(self, ctx):
        ctx.voice_client.resume()
        await ctx.send("Возабновлено.")


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Music(client))
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

add an exception so if someone tries command twice it will send them error.

try this:

```py
@commands.command()
async def play(self, ctx, url):
    try:
        if ctx.author.voice is None:
            await ctx.send("Вы не находитесь в голосовом канале !")
        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            await voice_channel.connect()
        else:
            await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)
        ctx.voice_client.stop()
        FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {
            'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5',
            'options': '-vn'
        }
        YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio'}
        vc = ctx.voice_client

        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
            url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
            source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
            vc.play(source)
    except discord.ClientException:
        await ctx.send("Already Playing Song")
```

Comment: but i have problem in another thing. I write my errors and pinned screenshots of tracebakcs

Comment: i didnt understand.